# Is it possible to resolve this proposition?

Tags: logic

Executing this code (see [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894525/quadratic-inequality-puzzle-prove-cx2-bx-a-%E2%89%A4-2-given-ax2bxc-%E2%89%A4-1) for its background)

```
ForAll[{a, b, c}, Implies[ForAll[x, -1 <= x <= 1, RealAbs[a*x^2 + b*x + c] <= 1], 
 ForAll[x, -1 <= x <= 1, RealAbs[c*x^2 + b*x + a] <= 2]]]
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

, I obtain

> Beep:The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation.

Can somebody with a powerful comp kindly execute it and report us the result? It would be very kind of her/him.

Comment: `FindInstance[! Implies[Resolve[ForAll[x, -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= a x^2 + b x + c <= 1], Reals], -2 <= c x^2 + b x + a <= 2] && -1 <= x <= 1, {x, a, b, c}]` returns `{}`, which would imply that there are no results for which this implication wouldn't hold, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Also: `Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c}, Implies[Resolve[ForAll[x, -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= a x^2 + b x + c <= 1], Reals], Resolve[ForAll[x, -1 <= x <= 1, -2 <= c x^2 + b x + a <= 2], Reals]]], Reals]` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @kirma: Thank you. Can you transform your second comment to an answer, elaborating it in details?

Comment: @kirma: Unfortunately, in your first comment you did a logical mistake: $x$ is a bound variable.

Comment: These are some of the things I'm worried about... but `With[{eq = Resolve[ForAll[x, -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= a x^2 + b x + c <= 1], Reals]}, FindInstance[! Implies[eq, -2 <= c x^2 + b x + a <= 2] && -1 <= x <= 1, {x, a, b, c}]]` should, at least, resolve this problem. Frankly I thought the first `Resolve` would evaluate early enough not to cause trouble here - or does it?

Comment: @karma: I repeat you made a logical mistake in your first comment: && -1 <= x <= 1 is superflous and {a,b,c} should stand instead of {x,a,b,c} in FindInstance. Also the negation of ForAll is Exists. Don't hesitate to ask  for further explanation in need..

Comment: `x` is there in order `FindInstance` to look for a solution (over `a`, `b`, `c` and also `x`) which would prove the implication wrong on that range for the last part of `Implies` under `FindInstance`. No solution to that was found, which should prove that implication is right.

Comment: @karma: Sorry,I have nothing to discuss with you in such manner.  I prefer arguments over ungrounded claims.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c}, 
  Implies[Resolve[ForAll[x, -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= a x^2 + b x + c <= 1],
     Reals], 
   Resolve[ForAll[x, -1 <= x <= 1, -2 <= c x^2 + b x + a <= 2], 
    Reals]]], Reals]
```

> True

In addition to replacing `RealAbs` (which might complicate `Resolve` unnecessarily) with corresponding range checks, I `Resolve` parts of `Implies` early. These result somewhat complicated intermediate results, but apparently they're easier for top-level `Resolve` to handle than multiple `ForAll`s inside each other.

Resolving `ForAll`s and `Exists` tends to be a bit of black art at times. I think I didn't really change the semantics in this case...